# Container width not matching viewport width on mobile device

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, viewport

I recoded my site for responsive design and set the HTML viewport, javascript, and CSS for the outer container `div` as shown below. On mobile browsers (Opera and Firefox) I have the following  problem:

- In portrait mode (only) the page loads correctly but the window allows scrolling to the right where there is a column of blank space outside the page-container. I can pinch zoom out so that I can see the column of space. Setting `minimum-scale=1` only prevents the pinch zoom out, but you can still scroll to the right.

Setting `overflow-x` prevents scrolling to the right but this seems dangerous (If there is data to the right for whatever reason, you want to be able to get to it).

Notes:

- Landscape mode works correctly.
- Desktop mode is correct except for a tiny bit of scrolling to the right. The more I zoom in however (viewport approximating mobile and beyond), the more the blank space on the right increases.

**Any idea why this space to the right and how to get rid of it?**

HTML

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

CSS (relevant)

```
.page-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-width:240px;
}
```

JS

```
var jmq = window.matchMedia("screen and (max-width: 610px)");
jmq.addListener(jmqListener);

function jmqListener(jmq){
    if (jmq.matches || window.innerWidth < 611 ) {
        //Mobile or zoomed in desktop - resize controls
        ...
    } else {
        // full desktop site
        ...
    }
```

A picture is worth a thousand words - the extra space is on the right:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have fixed widths on some of the elements in your header.

`.sitemessage h2` has a fixed width of 470px

`.sitename` has a fixed width of 475px

Setting those widths to auto will correct the issue.

Comment: Thank you! Especially for going above and beyond to find my website to solve this. In the redesign, I changed (almost) all my widths. Working like a charm now.